# How to connect to a docker box running elasticsearch inside a vagrant guest os?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, vagrant

I'm trying to start a vagrant box that in turn pulls in a docker elasticsearch image...

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # virtualbox provider for ububtu box
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.provision "docker"

  #pull docker image from https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/elasticsearch/
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.pull_images "elasticsearch"
    d.run "elasticsearch"
  end

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.150"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

end
```

I can then `vagrant ssh` into the vagrant box,
run `docker inspect [image id]` to get the ip address of the running docker image and run this...

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl -X GET http://172.17.0.2:9200
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Nocturne",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.4",
    "build_hash" : "c88f77ffc81301dfa9dfd81ca2232f09588bd512",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-02-19T13:05:36Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.3"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So elasticsearch is running fine. The problem is the 172.17.0.2 ip is dynamic. So if I want to access elasticsearch from the guest OS I need to inspect the docker image to get it.

Can I define the 172.17.0.x ip address with vagrant?
Is there a better way to 'discover' elasticsearch in the docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to expose the elasticsearch port on the vagrant IP. You should be able to do this within the `d.run` section along the lines of:

```
d.run "elasticsearch",
  args: "-p '9200:9200'"
```

(documentation is [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html))

Then you should be able to use the vagrant IP such as `curl 192.168.33.150:9200`